# CSS Submenus dropping a pixel with each ul

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to build my first purely CSS dropdown menu without any plugins, and I got it looking mostly how I want it, but one issue that I have is the drop downs seem to be "off" a pixel vertically, and they seem to drop down another pixel with each level.  I've tried throwing so many margin:0s and padding:0s I've lost track.  Figured I'd ask for help before I went crosseyed permanantly :)

The page/source/css can be viewed at bezaluhosting.com/testing/menu.htm

Comment: Please post your relevant code here, instead of having us go find it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `vertical-align: middle;` from `nav ul li {}`.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove `vertical-align: middle` from `nav ul li`

Comment: If you see that after you've added an answer, someone else had already gave the same answer sooner, it's good etiquette to remove your answer. I'm not just saying this because it was mine. I always remove my own answers if someone beats me to the same answer.

Comment: sorry about that I actually didnt see your answer